# How can I assign null value to an array element?

Tags: javascript

I am facing too small problem, could you give me idea how to solve that.

```
for(var j=cArray.length-1;j>=0;j--)
{
  if(cArray[j]=='.') {
    cArray[j]='';
    break;
  }
  else{
    cArray[j]='';
  }
}
```

I wrote this for loop in javascript.NULL value is not assigning to array element.
At last i am getting what is the content in cArray[j] only.I can't able to change that value.My declaration is correct or not?

Comment: The loop stops when you reach an array item that is '.'. Is that what you really want?

Comment: What does the array look like before, and what should it look like after the code you posted runs?

Comment: what exactly is your question? you are doing same thing in both `if() ` and `else` parts of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response

Comment: @Chandu: Are u trying to looping through blank array?

Comment: my input like "1.1.1" .if cArray[j] is '.' that time i will replace empty,in else i am doing both are not same
else {  levelNo +=cArray[j];          cArray[j]='';
 }

Comment: cArray = taskNo   ex: taskNo="1.1" like this

Comment: I see that you're trying to truncate an array like you might in C, by assigning NULL to an array item where you want the array to end. I've added an answer for that below.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish?

What the code does in this form is that it makes all elements in an array `''` (empty) that are after the last `'.'` element.

If you just want to truncate the array you could do somethink like this:

```
var jsArray = ['H','e','l','l','o','.','w','o','r','l','d'];
jsArray.length = 5;
alert(jsArray.length); // returns 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right. Maybe it is empty? See my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N9Fa8/1/) and observe as it works =)

Answer (score 0):

To truncate the array at the first `.`:

```
for(var j=cArray.length-1;j>=0;j--)
{
    if(cArray[j]=='.') {
        cArray.length = j;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or, if the array is really just a string:

```
var myString = "1.1.1";
var result = myString.split(".");
var firstPart = result[0];
```

`firstPart` now contains `1`.